# Should I stop my PostgreSQL server before reboot?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgresql-9.5

Every week I do an `apt-get upgrade` and `dist-upgrade` on the server where my PostgreSQL is running. After that, I do a `sudo reboot now`.

Should I stop the PostgreSQL service before this reboot?

Comment: It should be done by OS before it restarts.

Comment: Is this a production server?  I am asking because upgrading this way seems a bit unusual to me.

Comment: @dezso Yes, is a production server.

Comment: In that case, I'd stop doing this, and only upgrade when there is good reason for it - a CVE or other bug.  In my view, production servers should stay in a known good state as long as possible.

Comment: @dezso But every week there are updates available from both Ubuntu and other software.
Are these updates not important to ensure server security?

Comment: @Tom some are important, some are not.  I'd only touch stuff that is security or stability relevant.  Nowadays even kernels can be upgraded without rebooting, so I am not sure what is the connection between upgrades and reboots.

Comment: @dezso Usually after an update is made, logging into the terminal displays a message stating that it is necessary to reboot (*** System Restart Required **)

Comment: We have servers displaying this since several months.  The question is more if you need the reboot for something actually important, or it is some piece of software of minor importance requiring it.

Answer (score 1):

In theory the system should send it a stop signal and then wait for it to shutdown cleanly. But, I've seen this fail, with the result that the PostgreSQL had to go through crash recovery and any unlogged tables were truncated and had to be regenerated.  So I exercise an abundance of caution and manually shut PostgreSQL down before rebooting.

Comment: You should put it in the script and system will do it for you without your attention. Why don't?

Comment: @kakaz - as said in the answer text: caution because (s)he has seen this fail on occasions in the past. You are right, it *should* work, but manually stopping the service before a reboot does no harm: the scripted stop during the shutdown process will just become a NoOp or at worst it will log an error that the service was already stopped so it couldn't stop it. And if the manual stop is forgotten, the scripted one should just work and in either case if there are no other errors the service is stopped cleanly.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand probably. If you are administrator of your server, and you are complaining that reboot is not clean on your database, you should probably script it. Of course you may start and stop whatever you want, manually. Why not do manual stop for all services then? It is just the same level of convenience to stop manually ...

Comment: @kakaz It already is scripted, it comes with the system.  But it doesn't work 100% of the time. It is easier to manually shut it down than it is to fix a Heisenbug in someone else's code.

Comment: You are trying to say, that start-stop scripts for postgresql are  not correct and contain bugs? If so, now I understand. In this case you should put probably ticket on postgresql bugtrack or so. This is exactly the way open source platforms evolve to become better and better. Saying that I would remark that maybe there's something which clearly doesn't work for you. It may be worth to dig into it, because basically most of the time, for such popular platforms, this scripts works flawlessly. So don't ignore such kind of behavior, it may be a sign of something peculiar in your system!